# Angular5 Use Component from Module

Tags: angular, typescript

I am a noob with A5, doing my first 'component refactoring into modules.'  I'm trying to use a component that is defined in one module from another module.  I get the error, `ERROR in src/app/app-routing.module.ts(9,10): error TS2305: Module '"xxx/src/app/admin/admin.module"' has no exported member 'AdminHomeComponent'.`

I've looked at the other related questions, and I'm just plain missing something.  Hope you can help.

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ArchitectureComponent } from './architecture/architecture.component';
import { DesignComponent } from './design/design.component';
import { HistoryComponent } from './history/history.component';
import { AdminHomeComponent } from './admin/admin.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'architecture', component: ArchitectureComponent },
  { path: 'design', component: DesignComponent },
  { path: 'history', component: HistoryComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes)]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

src/app/admin/admin.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AdminHomeComponent } from './admin-home/admin-home.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    AdminHomeComponent
  ],
  declarations: [
    AdminHomeComponent  // <-- Tried adding this based on comments, no help
  ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

src/app/admin/admin-home/admin-home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-home',
  templateUrl: './admin-home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-home.component.scss']
})
export class AdminHomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And in case it helps,

src/app/app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import { TreeModule } from 'angular-tree-component';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
...
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ComponentsModule } from './components/components.module';
import { AdminModule } from './admin/admin.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
    HomeComponent,
    AdminModule   // <-- Tried adding this based on comments, but no help
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
    TreeModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AdminModule,
    ComponentsModule
  ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Maybe the answer is simple:  just import the component directly from the module?

But shouldn't I be able to use a component that is exported from a module, just by importing that component from the module?

Thx for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you import it from a module file you have to export it that way inside your admin.module.ts

```
  import { AdminHomeComponent } from './admin-home/admin-home.component';
  export {AdminHomeComponent };
```

Comment: Thanks, Fateh!  This did the trick.  But it confuses me.  Can you provide a pointer to doc about `export`?  I have not seen that in any examples.  THANK YOU!

Comment: inside your admin.module you don't have any exported class with the name AdminHomeComponent , so you have to export it that way then you can import it and use it as a component, but the best way is that you import the shared component from it's ts file "admin-home.component.ts"

Comment: but i suggest that you create a sharedModule and put everything shared like (components, services, pipes, directives ...) and you import it in another module when you need it, check this https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/feature-modules.html

Comment: Thanks, Fateh!  I appreciate the examples, but again, they do not include a child component of a module where the module exports the child component.  So they do NOT export { XxxComponent }; This was my issue as you pointed out ... how should one use a Component from a shared module?  And how should that module export the Component?

Comment: Fateh, specifically, in this example, the app imports the Component from the Component file, NOT the Module.  Is that the best practice?  Or should I use export in the Component that is a child of the Module (as you helped me do here)?

Comment: this works only if you import the component from the module file but for sure the best is to import it from it's file :)

Answer (score 0):

You're importing from the wrong file.

```
import { AdminHomeComponent } from './admin/admin.module';
```

Replace `module` with `component` in the filename.

Comment: Thx, Lazar, but there is no admin.component.  This is a module.

Comment: This is EXACTLY the problem you had, but OK.

Comment: Thx, Lazar, but ... I did not (and still do not) understand how to translate what you said into a solution to my question.  @Fateh's answer said I should add an `export {}`.  This solved my issue.  But I'm still not sure it is the best way to do this.  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Well you forgot to declare it in the module

Try this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AdminHomeComponent } from './admin-home/admin-home.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    AdminHomeComponent
  ],
  declarations: [AdminHomeComponent]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

And also i found out that in **app-routing.module.ts:** you have `import { AdminHomeComponent } from './admin/admin.module';` remove it.

instead in the **src/app/admin/admin.module** do it like this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AdminHomeComponent } from './admin-home/admin-home.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: 'admin', component: AdminHomeComponent } 
  ])
  ],
  exports: [
    AdminHomeComponent
  ],
  declarations: [AdminHomeComponent]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks, Amaya, but that did not help.  Shouldn't it be sufficient to declare it as an export?

Comment: yes its not because every component needs to be declared.

Comment: Thx, Amaya, ... does this component as described need to be declared?  It does not seem to matter from what I have tried so far.

Comment: Try rebuilding your application

Comment: Error comes from `ng build`

Comment: $ ng build
...

ERROR in src/app/app-routing.module.ts(9,10): error TS2305: Module '"src/app/admin/admin.module"' has no exported member 'AdminHomeComponent'.

Comment: (actual is too long)

Comment: have you tried removing `import { AdminHomeComponent } from './admin/admin.module';` in **app-routing.module.ts** and doing ng build again?

Comment: Yes, but I need that Component in the route.  So it fails with:
ERROR in src/app/app-routing.module.ts(17,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AdminHomeComponent'.

Comment: Because of:
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'architecture', component: ArchitectureComponent },
  { path: 'design', component: DesignComponent },
  { path: 'history', component: HistoryComponent },
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminHomeComponent }
];

Comment: Thx, Amaya -- where are you suggesting the "import from" ... component?  Is it not possible to export a component from a module, then import that component from that module?  If so, what's the point of modules?

Comment: import the `AdminModule ` in to the `AppRoutingModule `

Comment: Thx, Amaya -- so ... I cannot import from the module, even though the module exports that component?  I must directly import from the component (inside the module) ... and the exports from the module.ts file is ignored?